# Bernoulli Equation Normal to the Streamline

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, aerodynamics

Good Evening,

I'm thinking about the expression of the Bernoulli Principle in the *tangential* and *normal* directions of a StreamLine.

A. Along the streamline :

$$\gamma z \ + p \ + \frac{1}{2} \rho v^2 \ = \ \mathrm{Constant}$$

B. Across the streamline : $$p \ + \gamma z \ + \rho \int \frac {v^2}{R} dn \ = \ \mathrm{Constant}$$

My question is:

If I solve the velocity field in a fluid dynamics problem, and the I solve the pressure field using the Bernoulli Principle along the streamlines... will the Bernoulli equation **normal** to the streamlines also be satisfacted inside the field? I mean, if I consider the trend of the pressure (calculated with Bernoulli along the streamlines) in a normal direction to a streamiline, will this pressure satisfy the Bernoulli principle normal to the streamlines?

I have this doubt because we derive the Bernoulli Principle in two ortogonal direction, so why the Principle along the streamline should result in a pressure field that satisfy the Principle in the normal direction? They seems to not communicate each other.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi. What does $n$ stand for?

Comment: Hi, thanks to be here.

Well, " n " represent the normal direction to the streamline, while " s " tipically represent the tangential direction.

Comment: The Bernoulli Equation applies only in the streamline direction.  This is because it is the result of dotting the Euler equation with the velocity vector.

Comment: So what happens to the Bernoulli equation normal to a streamline? It is responsable of the curvature of the streamline ( the pressure gradient in normal direction determines the centripetal force). Is that equation not satisfacted?